# Importing a native React Component

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript

I am trying to use a React component from React Bootstrap in my rum app.

In my macros namespace I have some code that I [found on the rum gitter](https://gitter.im/tonsky/rum?at=55d73ec2fcfd5a7865aec0d6) :

```
(defn ->kebab [s]
  (str/join "-" (map str/lower-case (re-seq #"\w[a-z]+" s))))


(defn gen-wrapper [component]
  `(defmacro ~(symbol (->kebab (str component))) [& args#]
     (let [[opts# & [children#]] (if (-> args# first map?)
                                   [(first args#) (rest args#)]
                                   [nil args#])]
       `(js/React.createElement
         ~(symbol "js" (str "window.ReactBootstrap." (name '~component)))
         (cljs.core/clj->js ~opts#)
         ~@children#))))


(def components '[Button
                  ])

(defmacro gen-wrappers []
  `(do
     ~@(clojure.core/map gen-wrapper components)))
```

Then in my devcard namespace I have:

```
(pm/gen-wrappers)

(rum/defc foo []
  [:div (button nil "bggg")])

(defcard foo "" (foo))
```

The error is:

> react.inc.js:18342 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are
>   not valid as a React child (found: js/React.createElement). If you
>   meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap
>   the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check
>   the render method of `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with clojurescript macros. Note that the macro `gen-wrappers` itself expands to a series of macros -- in this case the `button` macro. But in clojurescript, you can't call a macro that was [defined in the same compilation stage](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure), which I unfortunately tried to do by calling `button` right away.

The solution was to move the gen-wrappers call into the macros file along with the other macros:

```
(defmacro gen-wrappers []
  `(do
     ~@(clojure.core/map gen-wrapper components)))

(gen-wrappers)
```

And then call the fully qualified `pm/button` from my devcard namespace.

```
(rum/defc foo []
  [:div (pm/button nil "bggg")])
```

"But wait!" you say. "Aren't you making the same mistake here of calling one macro (gen-wrappers) from the same compilation stage it was defined in? Actually no, because in clojurescript, macros are defined in *clojure* files, in which that restriction does not apply.